# How to bypass itms-services://?action=download-manifest UIAlertView in iOS?

Tags: ios

We are using below lines to install new app to device.

```
NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"itms-services://?action=download-manifest&amp;url=https://xxxxxx.com/rest/images/apps/ipa/dev/xyz.plist"]];
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:url];
```

It displays an `UIAlertView` with message "xxxxxx would like to install "xyz"".

Is there anyway either to bypass this alert view and forcefully install the ipa or any method callback sothat i can recognise that user pressed cancel button?

Answer (score 0):

No, There is no way to bypass that popup and just install the app on users phone. This behavior prevents any app to install app on your device without the users permission.

Comment: There is a way, You can check version in plist file and what is your current application version if application version is lower than plist version that means there is an updated version of application to download. In this case you can add a popup to hit itms-service URL again until user is not installing updated application.


Comment: but you need not to approach this.