# Any option to customize popups which are provided by itms-services?

Tags: ios, objective-c

I have an iOS app that can be upgraded via the web (in-house deployment). When a user shows the popup like "servername.domain.com" I would like to install "application name" and options are Cancel and Install.

My question is when I use itms-service to upgrade my app, then is there any option to install forcefully or hide the cancel button?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34716778/how-to-bypass-itms-services-action-download-manifest-uialertview-in-ios your colleague ? Anyway, practically the same question.